# Which After Effects renderer performs better on a macbook pro? RenderGarden or BG Renderer MAX?

Tags: after-effects, mac, rendering, macbook

I've got a 2018 MacBook Pro 15 inch with the built in Radeon Pro Vega 20 4 GB graphics.

I'd like to speed up rendering in After Effects.  Which of these is more effective at doing this and why?

- https://aescripts.com/bg-renderer/      $69
- https://www.mekajiki.com/rendergarden/  $99

Are there benchmarks anywhere for these kinds of things?
thanks

Comment: Both sites put a comparison to the native renderer on display: RenderGarden is supposedly 3.3 times faster while BG-Renderer MAX is 5.45 times faster. Does that answer your question though?

Comment: Interested in how it works on a macbook pro without a very powerful separate gfx card

Answer (score 0):

It seems in my experience that render garden is only helpful when you have a network or farm of machines that you can distribute the render to. If you have only a single machine, I'd say BG Render is your best bet. If you have a farm, Render Garden is better. But, either one will speed up your render since both take advantage of multi threading that after effects' render doesn't seem to use/like natively...